# Is there a way to get original .java contents from .class file in compiled jar file

Tags: java, maven, class, intellij-idea, jar

We have jar files on the server that are run on a schedule, but I don't think the code I found is matching what's on the server.  What's in clearcase does not have jar files to compare sizes/dates.

Is there a way to extract the original .java text contents from the .class files when I open the .jar file with 7-zip? The class contents have garbage in them since they are a result of compiling. Then I can compare the class contents with what I found in clearcase and see if the errors I'm seeing were in the release a few years ago. The people who worked on this don't work here anymore.

I'm not finding what I'm looking for in an internet search. It could be it's not possible. In my search, I'm just finding how to unzip the jar file and see the .class files there but not the original class text contents.

I'm using SDK 1.8.0_2-2, SDK default 8 (lambdas etc).

Thank you!

Comment: Getting `.java` files back from `.class` files is called decompiling. You can do it, but you won't get "the original .java" files back. If you're lucky, you'll get something that will end up compiling back into the same binary, but the reconstruction is not perfect. And since you tagged this as intellij-idea for some reason: IDEA comes with a decompiler built in, IIRC, so opening the jar in there should allow you to few the decompilation result.

Comment: @JoachimSauer - if I'm seeing a hard-coded date in the clearcase code, would the decompiled file have the code showing if the date is hard-coded?

Comment: Yes, *usually* the decompiled code will be effectively equivalent, but it will be missing niceties like local variable names, comments and formatting. If the jar file has been intentionally obfuscated, then the decompilation result could be worse (or not get produced at all).

Comment: Technically you will never get the original java source because things like comments etc. and local variable names etc. can not be decompiled. You will get a source file which is equivalent in function ( I can remenber there had been some issues with that)... furthermore why using such old JDK version ?

Comment: @JoachimSauer - thank you for this info.  I searched for videos on how to convert .class file to .java file, and found a video that referred to javadecompilers.com.  I used this to upload my class file and it converted it to a .java source code.  I noticed that the date is hard-coded to 2018 in this version too, which is what I needed to know.  Thank you so much for giving me enough info to search and find out how to do this!

Comment: @khmarbaise -  we are tied to an old java version because of what is running on our server.  The programs running there were built with the older java version. I tried compiling mine with a newer java version a few months ago, and once I try running it on the server, it gets an error about using the wrong java version.

Comment: What kind of servers? (Tomcat, WebSphere, JBoss etc.)? Apart from that this old version has a lot of security vulnerbilities even while running in a Server... Current version of [JDK 8](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/8u-relnotes.html) ...even the current state of encryption parts (TLS etc.)